# AFNetworking image download without using AFImageRequestOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, asynchronous, afnetworking-2

I want to download a image from url and get NSData in response object.

This is how I set up the operation:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

AFHTTPResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"image/jpeg"];
manager.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;

AFHTTPRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
[requestSerializer setValue:@"image/jpeg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[requestSerializer setValue:@"image/jpeg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;

[manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSData *data = responseObject;

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Response object is always nil, url is correct, when openned in browser it shows up the image, the operation descriptions shows content-length and content type(image/jpeg), but response object doesn't seem to pick it up.

Thank you

**Answer:**  instead of responseObject, operation.reponseData need to be used.

Comment: @AdamEberbach it is not a duplicate, it's not the same thing.

Comment: do you access `operation.reponseData` in the failure block?

Comment: In success block, no error occurs.

Comment: And what is the reason you don't what to deserialize it?

Comment: You can try SDWebImage, it is easy to do such an operation. https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: @vikingosegundo it is business logic reason.

Comment: what can be a business logic if you download raw data from the web but don't stream it onto your disk instead hold it in memory. if you  do not intend to use it as images I don't see any valid reason for that. and streaming directly to disk with low memory footprint is done differently.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to tell AFNetworking that you expect image data and that to should be deserialized as that.

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
```

[AFImageResponseSerializer Class Reference](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFImageResponseSerializer.html)

> By default, AFImageSerializer accepts the following MIME types, which
>   correspond to the image formats supported by UIImage or NSImage:
>
> ```
> image/tiff
> image/jpeg
> image/gif
> image/png
> image/ico
> image/x-icon
> image/bmp
> image/x-bmp
> image/x-xbitmap
> image/x-win-bitmap
> ```

---

> Answer: instead of responseObject, operation.reponseData need to be used.

if you would user proper serialization, it would be responseObject, transformed into a object you can immediately use. operation.reponseData contains the raw data sent from the server. usually it is not what you need.

Comment: I told AFnetworking already that I expect a data image,see the response serializer ? And operation recognized that image is in the response,it doesn't put the image data into the responseObject. I solved it in the meantime. will update the answer now.

Comment: but why do u skip to turn it into an image object?